# How to use your PDF reader instead of Google Docs in Gmail?

Tags: firefox, pdf, google-docs, foxit-reader

I prefer Foxit Reader over Google Docs, but whenever I receive a PDF file over Gmail I have to either download it or view it in Google Docs.

**Is there a script (or any other way) to open Gmail PDF files on my browser's standard PDF reader (Foxit) instead of Google Docs?**

If it's relevant, I use Firefox and Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you activate the Foxit Reader Firefox plugin (which can be done when installing Foxit Reader or through Firefox' *Tools menu->Add-ons->Plugins->Foxit Reader Plugin for Mozilla*), you can then click the attachment link Download (instead of View) and you will get the option to see it in Firefox through that plugin.

**You cannot** use Foxit reader without downloading the attachment. It will however be downloaded to a temp folder and removed once you close the firefox tab where the document is being displayed.

Comment: Well that's simple =). I do have the plugin installed, and would have seen this if I hadn't set firefox to automatically skip the "Download or open" messagebox. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose print from the file menu, then cancel print.
Google docs switches to Adobe Reader in order to print.