# View attached pdf in Gmail using browser plugin instead of Google Docs?

Tags: pdf, gmail, browser-addons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use your pdf reader instead of google docs in gmail?](https://superuser.com/questions/57085/how-to-use-your-pdf-reader-instead-of-google-docs-in-gmail)

If I receive an email with an attached pdf in Gmail, clicking view will open it in Google Docs. How do I make it open using the browser plugin? I'm using Foxit.

Comment: Which Browser ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot make it open in the browser plug-in directly. **However you can click the download button, select open with, making sure your desired reader is selected.**

I generally do not like PDF files opening inside a plug-in in the browser, as a lot of the time it makes the browser unstable. So opening outside the browser is recommended.